# "java.exe" exited with code 1 , Xamarin.Android.Common.targets

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

When i exported my project from Vs2019(professional 16.11.0) to Vs2022(Community) i am facing the following issue.

`` Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined ``

i have worked around some solutions and set android:exported as true for Receivers but it did not work , Any suggestions on how to overcome this error, that would be great help.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

At first, please check all the Activities, Services and BroadcastReceivers in your project which have an intent filter whether have the `android:exported`.

And you can try to debug and find which component caused this issue. In addtion, sometimes the `android:exported` only be declared in the AndroidManifest.xml can work, such as [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71621559/application-doest-buil-whit-android-12-firebase-messaging/71641854#71641854).